# Jmeter Soap Plugin - What "Variable definition panel" is used for?

Tags: soap, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-3.2

I download JMeter's [Soap Sampler plugin](https://github.com/spinning10/JMeterSoapSampler/wiki)

I notice that there's a new `Variable definition panel` Config Element

But I don't understand what is purpose and usage. I tried to use it but no impact

Do anyone know its purpose/usage and relevant to Soap?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use it to set one JMeter variable using a large panel, for example:

Enter Variable Name: myVar

Variable contents: myValue

It will create JMeter variable myVar=myValue

Also the difference from [User Defined Variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Defined_Variables), is that it can override previous value.